# I'm trying to plot a pie chart using data from a CSV file but I'm getting an error I don't understand

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is the code I've tried. SS of the CSV file and the error are attached below.

```
def displayGraph():
    with open('seats.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        s = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    
        x=0
        y=0
    
        for p in range(48):
            if s[p]==0:
                x+=1
    
        for g in range(48):
            if s[g]==1:
                y+=1
            
    a=x/(x+y)  *100
    b=y/(x+y)  *100
    
    graph=[a,b]
    plt.pie(graph, labels=['Empty Seats', 'Booked Seats'])
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiAJM.jpg    Error (part 1)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cnrb.jpg    Error (part 2)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbV2d.jpg  CSV File

### Edit

CSV file provided below in text format:

```
0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1  

0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1  

1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0  

0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1  

0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0  

1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1
```

Comment: Please do not post **images**. A csv file is a plain text file. If you add it *as text* to the question we will be able to reproduce, which is the first step to a solution.

Comment: BTW, `newline=''` is required to use the csv module. It is useless with pandas, and `pd.read_csv` can directly accept a file name.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Made the change to the post. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

The csv module and Pandas are two ways for processing CSV files, but apart from that they are unrelated and are used differently. Here you have loaded your file with pandas and used it as is you had used a `csv.reader`. You should choose one.

`csv` module way

```
with open('seats.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    s = csv.reader(csvfile)
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for row in s:
        for val in row:
            if val == '1':        # csv module sets values as strings...
                y += 1
            else:
                x += 1

a=x/(x+y)  *100
b=y/(x+y)  *100

graph=[a,b]
plt.pie(graph, labels=['Empty Seats', 'Booked Seats'])
```

Pandas way (more *magic* here...)

```
df = pd.read_csv('seats.csv', header = None)
y = df.sum().sum()
x = len(df) * len(df.columns) - y

a=x/(x+y)  *100
b=y/(x+y)  *100

graph=[a,b]
plt.pie(graph, labels=['Empty Seats', 'Booked Seats'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried actually looking at the content of the DataFrame?

You access DataFrame like this in Python:

table.csv:

```
  A  |  B  |  C 
-----------------
 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3
------------------
 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6
------------------
```

script:

```py
pd.read_csv("table.csv")

print(list(pd["A"]))
```

OUTPUT

```
[0.1,0.4]
```

Your csv does not have any column names so you cannot just do s[p], which is why it is throwing KeyError: 0 (the column called "0" does not exist in your csv)

You need to use iloc:
(if the p is referring to the column index)

```
s.iloc[:,p]
```

or if p is referring to the row index

```
s.iloc[p,:]
```

Comment: Made the changes to the code. I'm getting this error now.. https://imgur.com/eHjvjkL